# automatically add selected to dropdown menu using GET variable

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, symfony1, get, symfony-1.4

I am using a captcha in a form. When the user submits an invalid answer to the captcha, the page reloads repopulating the fields with the user data. My question is, is there a better (or easier) way to check which dropdown value was selected.

This is what I have now that works:

**php**

```
<?php
    $state = $sf_params->get('state'); 
?>
```

**html**

```
<span>State </span>
    <select size="1" name="state">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="AL" <?php if ($state == "AL") { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?>>Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK" <?php if ($state == "AK") { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?>>Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ" <?php if ($state == "AZ") { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?>>Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR" <?php if ($state == "AR") { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?>>Arkansas</option>
```

Is there another solution to getting the GET variable, then parsing the options, looking for the matched value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First move the values of the select to an array in the Controller like

```
$states = array('AL' => 'Alabama', ... );
```

Then you can use the Helper j0k mentioned or go by feet:
By assigning the vars in the controller.

```
$this->states = $states;
```

In the Template:

```
<?php foreach ($states as $key => $value): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php if ($state == $value) { echo "selected = 'selected'"; } ?>><?php echo $value ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But I also recommend to use the Helper.

Comment: In this scenario, I am working entirely in the view. This form is a partial that is getting pulled into a template.

Comment: ok but you can pass vars to a partial: <?php include_partial('mypartial', array('states' => $states)) ?>. So store the states somewhere in the code and pass them to the partial then you can at least use a foreach.

Comment: Yep, that sounds good. Just doing some final testing, but I think your solution fits what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not really a good practice to build a form on your own. Usually you should use widget from sfForm class, etc ..

But, if you really want to build this kind of stuff, you should bring back a good helper from sf1.0 that helps you building form tag. In your case, the function [`options_for_select`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/lib/helper/FormHelper.php#L22) and [`select_tag`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.0/lib/helper/FormHelper.php#L140) might be useful:

- `options_for_select`:

  > Returns a formatted set of `<option>` tags based on optional `$options` array variable.
- `select_tag`:

  > Returns a `<select>` tag, optionally comprised of `<option>` tags.

`options_for_select` took as second parameter, the selected value you want.

So just, create a file called `lib/helper/FormHelper.php` and put these two functions inside. Don't forget to load the helper in your view :

```
<?php use_helper('Form') ?>
```

And use `options_for_select` & `select_tag` to build your select.

Comment: This form is a custom form that is generated from serialized data. That is why it is built in the traditional html fashion. Each form is setup as a partial and pulled into the template according to a routing variable. This is already in place in development, so there is no going back :)